# jquery: ordinal of td inside tr

Tags: jquery, html-table, ordinals

I have a row in an html-table that contains only images. (this happens to be the first row too). Those images are wired for a click event too. While trying to handle the click event I can find out its parent (i.e. `<td>` element). But I want to know its relative ordinal in the table row (`<tr`>).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the ordinal with the `index()` function:

```
$('td img').click(function() {
   var ordinal = $(this).closest('tr').children().index($(this).parent());
   // ...
});
```

Comment: I realise this is old but I just tried this and ordinal is always -1 :/

$("td").click(function () {
                var ordinal = $(this).closest('tr').children().index($(this).parent());
                alert(ordinal);
            });

Comment: You should do: `$("td").click(function () { var ordinal = $(this).closest('tr').children().index(this); alert(ordinal); });` The original had `$(this).parent()` because `this` referred to the img element inside the td; but in your case `this` is the td itself.

Answer (score 1):

The number of elements before the current element will be its index in the DOM relative to the parent.  You can use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) and get the length of the resulting set:

```
$('td').click(function(){
  alert($(this).prevAll().length);
});
```

[Demo available on jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/DsU5e/)